# Disable root node refresh on window focus

Tags: macvim, nerdtree

Whenever I focus my MacVim window it freezes for several seconds. It seems that this is due to NERDTree refreshing it's root node (It prints `NERDTree: Refreshing root node. This could take a while... DONE`)

Since I often switch in and out of MacVim this is very annoying and slows down my workflow. Is there a way of configuring NERDTree not to do this automatically?

EDIT: I am using janus

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you're using janus.  [Janus adds a FocusGained event](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/0e34a62fac3a38ccc459bf3a6dab6ef1ec6dc9a5/janus/vim/tools/janus/after/plugin/nerdtree.vim#L9), and so when you do `:au FocusGained` as Kazuki mentioned, you'll see something like:

```
AuNERDTreeCmd  FocusGained
    *         call s:UpdateNERDTree()
```

You can remove that focus event binding by adding the following to your `.vimrc.after`:

```
autocmd! AuNERDTreeCmd FocusGained
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked! I was indeed using janus (I really should have mention in my question - I'm going to add that now). One small comment - I think in janus the appropriate file to add the above command to is `.vimrc.after`

Answer (score 2):

I think [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) itself doesn't do refresh the root node automatically. Actually I can't reproduce the problem. You need to [input `R` key (default) to refresh the root node](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L498-L506).

> Whenever I focus my MacVim window it freezes for several seconds

It sounds you are using [FocusGained](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#FocusGained) autocommand event to do something. You can check it using the following command.

```
:au FocusGained
```

You will get the list of FocusGained autocommand events.

```
--- Auto-Commands ---
FocusGained
    * ...
```

For example, you can auto-refresh NERDTree root like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/524856).

Comment: Thanks, Kazuki - that pointed me in the correct direction, but I ended up accepting BBonifield's answer because he provided a remedy with it.